React + GSAP Text Animation Stutters on Initial Page Load but Works Fine on Hot Reload
I'm experiencing a strange issue with GSAP text animations in my React component. The animation stutters/gets stuck during initial page load or refresh on all devices, but works perfectly during hot reload in development.
Code:
...
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import SplitType from 'split-type';
import gsap from "gsap";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const HeroSection = () => {
   const headingRef = useRef(null);
  const bodyRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const text = new SplitType(headingRef.current, { types: 'chars' });
    const body = new SplitType(bodyRef.current, { types: 'chars' });

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      defaults: {
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: "back.out",
      }
    });

    tl.from(text.chars, {
      opacity: 0,
      y: 20,
      rotateX: -90,
      stagger: 0.05
    })
      .from(body.chars, {
        opacity: 0,
        x: 50,
        stagger: 0.01,
        ease: "power2.out"
      }, "-=0.3"); 

    return () => {
      text.revert();
      body.revert();
      tl.kill();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
...
         <div className="overflow-hidden">
              <h1
                ref={headingRef}
                className="font-light text-5xl md:text-6xl lg:text-7xl text-black leading-[1.1] mb-8 opacity-0">
                //heading text
              </h1>
              <p ref={bodyRef} className="text-sm md:text-base text-black/70 max-w-md mb-12 leading-relaxed opacity-0">
                //body text
              </p>
         </div>
...

Following are the demonstrations of outputs:
On intial loading:

On hot reloading:

What I've Tried:

Added delay to animation start
Used gsap.context()
Added willChange: 'transform'
Adjusted timing and easing

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?
